# open-ssl only encrypts strings that have more than 15 characters

Tags: php, php-openssl

im using open-ssl in a project and want to encrypt firstname and surname of users. I discovered a strange behavior from open-ssl: only strings that have more than 15 characters are encrypted. Is it my fault or something not documented?

```
<?php

$cipher = 'aes-256-xts';
$privateKey = 'LOOK';
$stringToEncrypt = "Luisa 111 111 11";

$ivLength = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivLength);

$encryptedData = openssl_encrypt($stringToEncrypt, $cipher, $privateKey, 0, $iv) . ":" . base64_encode($iv);

list($encryptedString, $iv) = explode(':', $encryptedData, 2);

$decryptedData = openssl_decrypt($encryptedString, $cipher, $privateKey, 0, base64_decode($iv));
```

Does anybody know a solution for my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Switch to `aes-256-cbc`. However, I'm curious what you mean by 15+ encrypts. What happens when its 14 characters long? Does it encrypt, but not decrypt, or does it spit the unencrypted value out, or does it error, or ...

Comment: Also, ensure your private key is 32 raw bytes. No more, no less.

Comment: @IncredibleHat ... with aes-256-xts $encryptedData contains only the iv, but obviously nothing is encrypted when the unencrypted value contains 15 or less characters. No error or notice is thrown.

Comment: Thanks to @IncredibleHat - changing cipher to aes-256-cbc was the clue - now openssl_encrypt works as intended. I can encrypt data with even one character!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Changing the cipher to aes-256-cbc allows to encrypt strings with only one character.